# Labeled LDA learn in Stanford Topic Modeling Toolbox

Tags: stanford-nlp, topic-modeling

It's ok when I run the example-6-llda-learn.scala as follows:

```
val source = CSVFile("pubmed-oa-subset.csv") ~> IDColumn(1);

val tokenizer = {
  SimpleEnglishTokenizer() ~>            // tokenize on space and punctuation
  CaseFolder() ~>                        // lowercase everything
  WordsAndNumbersOnlyFilter() ~>         // ignore non-words and non-numbers
  MinimumLengthFilter(3)                 // take terms with >=3 characters
}

val text = {
  source ~>                              // read from the source file
  Column(4) ~>                           // select column containing text
  TokenizeWith(tokenizer) ~>             // tokenize with tokenizer above
  TermCounter() ~>                       // collect counts (needed below)
  TermMinimumDocumentCountFilter(4) ~>   // filter terms in <4 docs
  TermDynamicStopListFilter(30) ~>       // filter out 30 most common terms
  DocumentMinimumLengthFilter(5)         // take only docs with >=5 terms
}

// define fields from the dataset we are going to slice against
val labels = {
  source ~>                              // read from the source file
  Column(2) ~>                           // take column two, the year
  TokenizeWith(WhitespaceTokenizer()) ~> // turns label field into an array
  TermCounter() ~>                       // collect label counts
  TermMinimumDocumentCountFilter(10)     // filter labels in < 10 docs
}

val dataset = LabeledLDADataset(text, labels);

// define the model parameters
val modelParams = LabeledLDAModelParams(dataset);

// Name of the output model folder to generate
val modelPath = file("llda-cvb0-"+dataset.signature+"-"+modelParams.signature);

// Trains the model, writing to the given output path
TrainCVB0LabeledLDA(modelParams, dataset, output = modelPath, maxIterations = 1000);
// or could use TrainGibbsLabeledLDA(modelParams, dataset, output = modelPath, maxIterations = 1500);
```

But it's not ok when I change the last line from:
   TrainCVB0LabeledLDA(modelParams, dataset, output = modelPath, maxIterations = 1000);
to:
   TrainGibbsLabeledLDA(modelParams, dataset, output = modelPath, maxIterations = 1500);

And the method of CVB0 cost much memory.I train a corpus of 10,000 documents with about 10 labels each document,it will cost 30G memory.

Comment: I think it's a bug since there is a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same situation and indeed I believe it's a bug. Check `GIbbsLabeledLDA.scala` in `edu.stanford.nlp.tmt.model.llda` under the `src/main/scala` folder, from line 204:

```
val z = doc.labels(zI);

val pZ = (doc.theta(z)+topicSmoothing(z)) *
         (countTopicTerm(z)(term)+termSmooth) /
         (countTopic(z)+termSmoothDenom);
```

`doc.labels` is self-explanatory, and `doc.theta` records the distribution (*counts*, actually) of its labels, which has the same size as `doc.labels`.

`zI` is index variable iterating `doc.labels`, while the value `z` gets the actual label number. Here comes the problem: it's possible this documents has only one label - say 1000 - therefore `zI` is 0 and `z` is 1000, then `doc.theta(z)` gets out of range.

I suppose the **solution** would be to modify `doc.theta(z)` to `doc.theta(zI)`.
(I'm trying to check whether the results would be meaningful, anyway this bug has made me not so confident in this toolbox.)